# preg_match to match files with .jpg/.png extension

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I am having a root folder `C:/wamp/www//scanner/scanner/`.
For eg: this folder contains  **directories**  `images`, `work`, `uploads` etc. I am using function `scan_dir` to scan all the folders and subfolders etc. 
I want to exclude the files with these extensions.

```
$except = array("rar", "zip", "mp3", "mp4", "mp3", "mov", "flv", "wmv", "swf", "png", "gif", "jpg", "bmp", "avi");
```

Please can anyone help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Because I assume you use a loop to go through the files. Why not ignore the filetypes there?

Comment: instead of exclude, how about you use the array for the files you want to include, it will be a smaller list i presume

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$except = array("rar", "zip", "mp3", "mp4", "mp3", "mov", "flv", "wmv", "swf", "png", "gif", "jpg", "bmp", "avi");
$imp = implode('|', $except);

foreach($files as $file)
{
    if(preg_match('/^.*\.('.$imp.')$/i', $file))
        echo $file;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like below?

```
$except = array("rar", "zip", "mp3", "mp4", "mp3", "mov", "flv", "wmv", "swf", "png", "gif", "jpg", "bmp", "avi");

if (!preg_match('/\.('.implode('|', $except).')$/', $filename, $matches)) {
  // ...
}
```